vue js 3 cdn fetch on initial page load
I'm using VueJS 3 (via a CDN) to fetch a list of files.
My code is working with a button click, but I would like to modify it to fetch files at the initial page load.
<script>
const {
  createApp,
  ref
} = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const files = ref([]);
    function getfiles() {
      const res1 = fetch('/api/files.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.requestfiles = data.data.files;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("There was an error! ", error)
      });
    }
    return {
      getfiles,
      files
    }
  }
}).mount('#app');
</script>


This is one way of doing things by using the CDN approach.


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-for="file in files" :key="file.id">
- {{ file.title }}
  </p>
</div>

<script>
const {
  createApp,
  ref
} = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
const files = ref([]);

async function getfiles() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
    const result = await response.json()
    files.value = result
  } catch(error) {
    console.error("There was an error! ", error)
  }
}
getfiles()

return {
  getfiles,
  files
}
  }
}).mount('#app');
</script>



Since you do not have a big project for now, you can keep things in the setup part, but then you could be more granular and use the created, mounted etc...lifecycle hooks.

thanks for the answer! this works for a single element but i would like to use all array elements from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

I've updated it with a v-for iteration from this page of the docs.
